# Screen does not turn off and random freezes with Radeon OSS modules on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: radeon, lock-screen, 20.10

Ever since installing an AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT my screens won't completely blank when I lock the screen. They turn off momentarily, then either the backlight will turn on, a black screen with the mouse cursor will appear (even if I unplug the mouse), or the lock screen will just appear and won't go away.

Another issue which I suspect is also related to this card is that the system will freeze sometimes when I lock the screen or suspend the machine. The screens freeze, the network is down (can't SSH into the machine and no real activity), and there are no logs recorded. There is also no ACPI response from the physical power button, forcing me to do a hard reboot.

I'm using GNOME on Ubuntu 20.10 (groovy) and the current kernel version is 5.8.0-29-generic. The screen was blanking properly with the previous card (an Nvidia GTX 980 with the proprietary driver installed).

Under the assumption the issue had to do with power control I tried:

- Disabling PCIe-ASPM in both the BIOS and in the kernel boot parameters
- Setting PCIe-ASPM to BIOS control only (no OS control)
- Setting PCIe-ASPM [back] to OS control

And none of these changes altered the behaviour of either the screen not blanking or the machine not recovering from suspend.

I can not find anything that seems to be relevant in syslog. There are no warnings that show up consistently before a freeze, and there are no warnings or errors that look to be related to the freeze.

I suspect this is an issue that may be resolved with a kernel update, but if anyone has any ideas or can give me a better idea of how to catch the issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be specifically associated with Display Port connected displays on Linux, perhaps even more specifically due to the AMD OSS drivers provided with the Ubuntu kernels. As AMD does not provide packages for the "pro" drivers for Ubuntu 20.10 I am unable to test them. *The problem does not appear in Windows and the displays do in fact black properly in Windows.

In my situation the RX 5600 XT card I have has a single HDMI and 3 Display Port ports - and I have 3 monitors. When I connect any of the monitors to one of the Display Port ports the inability to blank the displays and the freezing persists. If however I plug in one monitor to the HDMI everything is fine, and if I plug the other two into ports on my motherboard (one HDMI and one display port / onboard Intel graphics) everything still works fine; the screens properly blank and the system doesn't freeze.

As the problem only presents in Linux I can only assume it's an issue with the OSS modules distributed with the kernel; which will hopefully be fixed some time in the near future. In the mean time I will attempt to build a new kernel with the latest AMD provided OSS modules and will update this answer if this resolves the problem.